# Django template string comparison failed

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{{ is_true }}

{% if is_true == "True" %}
    <h2>Say True</h2>
{% else %}
    <h2> False </h2>
{% endif %}
```

But instead it went to `else` clause even though `{{ is_true }}` returns True

Any idea?

```
def some_func():
   if ....:
     return True
   else:
     return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `"True"` in your template:

```
{% if is_true == True %}
```

Or just:

```
{% if is_true %}
```

If you use `"True"` in your template then you are comparing the boolean `True` with the string  `"True"` (which are not the same) and end up in the `else` clause of your template.
In other words you would be doing:

```
{% if True == "True" %}
    <h2>Say True</h2>
{% else %}                     # You will end up here
    <h2> False </h2>
{% endif %}
```

You can find more info about Django's Template Language in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)